# how should i parse "text" value from below array object of json string?

Tags: python, json

["{\"contributors\": null, \"truncated\": false, \"text\": \"RT @itisprashanth: All petitions regarding #jallikattu to be heard by Supreme Court tomorrow. Tomorrow will be the D-Day for all the Youth\u2026\"}"]

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to give a reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Answer (score 2):

use the **json** module to convert string to json object.

**Ex:**

```
import json
h = ["{\"contributors\": null, \"truncated\": false, \"text\": \"RT @itisprashanth: All petitions regarding #jallikattu to be heard by Supreme Court tomorrow. Tomorrow will be the D-Day for all the Youth\u2026\"}"]
for i in h:
    v = json.loads(i)
    print v["text"]
```

**Output:**

```
RT @itisprashanth: All petitions regarding #jallikattu to be heard by Supreme Court tomorrow. Tomorrow will be the D-Day for all the Youth…
```

Answer (score 1):

Just parse the string (the first element of the given array) as a JSON object, and take its text value.

```
import json
arr = ["{"contributors": null, "truncated": false, "text": "RT @itisprashanth: All petitions regarding #jallikattu to be heard by Supreme Court tomorrow. Tomorrow will be the D-Day for all the Youth\u2026"}"]
print(json.loads(arr[0])["text"])
# "RT @itisprashanth: All petitions regarding #jallikattu to be heard by Supreme Court tomorrow. Tomorrow will be the D-Day for all the Youth\u2026"
```